# how do I pass a text box string in directory creation

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a directory structure using the following code.

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("G:\suppler\", txtsource.text)
```

I wish to pass the contents of my textbox to the xxxx but get an error stating that i can't pass a string.

Can you please advise how i can make the code work.

Comment: Is this C++ or C#?  I don't remember "System.IO.Directory" in C++.  I know it's in C#.

Comment: Use forward slashes, '/', in filenames, as it will relieve you of many burdens.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about [escape sequnces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape): `"G:\suppler\"` is not terminated, but contains a quote.